# How to take text from elements to use it later in cypress?

Tags: automated-tests, cypress

I need to take 2 lists of text values on page to use each of them in different cheking.
I do it by xpath

> ```
>     cy.xpath('//tbody/tr[position()<10]/td[6]/span').then(items => {
>         cy.wrap(items).as('multipleList')
>     })
>
>     cy.xpath('//tbody/tr[position()<21][position()>15]/td[6]/span').then(items => {
>         cy.wrap(items).as('commaList')
>     })
>
>     cy.get('@multipleList').each((qwer, index) => {..........})
>
>     cy.get('@commaList').each((qwer, index) => {..........})
> ```

But after using the first list (@multipleList), it shows error that the second list (@commaList) is empty.

If I swap them, then @commaList is being executed OK, but @multipleList shows the same error.

Comment: Are you accessing the aliases within the same `it` block ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a combined selection and iteration only once

```js
cy.xpath('//tbody/tr').as('list')

cy.get('@list').each(($rows, rowIndex) => {

  if (rowIndex < 9) {
    const $span = $rows[index].find('td:eq(6) span')
    ...
  }

  if (rowIndex > 14 && rowIndex < 20) {
    const $span = $rows[index].find('td:eq(6) span')
    ...
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

With the test as you've shown, it's not possible.

If you have an error it's the processing in `.each()` causing page changes (2nd list becomes invalid).

Try to reorder the commands

```js
cy.xpath('//tbody/tr[position()<10]/td[6]/span').as('multipleList')

cy.get('@multipleList').each((qwer, index) => {..........})


cy.xpath('//tbody/tr[position()<21][position()>15]/td[6]/span').as('commaList')

cy.get('@commaList').each((qwer, index) => {..........})
```